# Atomic Update One Using Waterline JS

Tags: sql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

## Goal

I want to update a single record based on search criteria (similar to findOne, but I want to updateOne). This has to be atomic though because a `.find() then .update()` would take advantage of the *wonderful* asynchronous nature of node and leave the record open for alteration after find and before update.

## Example

Let's say to simplify things that I have records of my possessions I want to loan to friends though a site. If two friends simultaneously wanted to borrow any book available, I would need to mark its attribute as in-use to prevent problems.

If I used `Book.find(available==true)` and then `Book.update(book, available=false)`, this could have a race condition where the thread runs `.find()` and while waiting to hear back from the DB, calls `.find()` for the other user, both resulting in the same book to loan. This is obviously a problem and is what I want to protect against.

## Question

How do I protect against this scenario? Is there a way to update one record using the helper methods of waterline? Or do I need to conduct a native SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

you can use mongodb native findAndModify():

```
 var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

 Book
  .native(function (err, collection) {
  collection.findAndModify(
    {_id: new ObjectId(Id), available: true},
    {$set:{ available: false}}, 
    { upsert: true }
    function (err, result) {
        // manage after update
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm aware that native is a possibility, as mentioned in my question. I wanted to know if is there a way to use sails/waterline to protect against the scenario mentioned without using a native SQL query.